# How do I set attributes when creating vectors using OpenLayers and WFS-T?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, wfs-t

I have published a WFS-T layer (using geoserver) and am able to add, edit and delete features using OpenLayers and it's Vector layer.

But, I don't know how can I populate additional attributes using OpenLayers and WFS-T. Any pointers?

Let's say I have database structure:

```
ARMY (
ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR2(200));

INVADED_AREA (
ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
INVADED_BY_ARMY_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
AREA_GEOMETRY SDO_GEOMETRY,
CONSTRAINT ia_fk FOREIGN KEY(INVADED_BY_ARMY_ID) REFERENCES ARMY(ID));
```

and I have a web application where you first select an army (with e.g. ID 42) and then start drawing geometries of invaded areas using OpenLayers. How do I get OpenLayers to put value 42 into INVADED_AREA.INVADED_BY_ARMY_ID column?

EDIT:
I have found http://dev4.mapgears.com/bdga/bdgaWFS-T.html# which seems to do what I am looking for. Will update when I have investigated it more.

Also found bunch of related gis.stackexchange questions. I will look through them more carefully, at first glance none had an easy answer:

- [I want to edit corresponding postgresql data of a vector from openlayers- how to do it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/i-want-to-edit-corresponding-postgresql-data-of-a-vector-from-openlayers-how-to?rq=1)
- [How to edit Attributes on WFS Layer through Popup?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31753/how-to-edit-attributes-on-wfs-layer-through-popup)
- [How to edit feature attributes with openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/how-to-edit-feature-attributes-with-openlayers)
- [Modify WFS with OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/modify-wfs-with-openlayers)
- [adding non spatial attributes using geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32243/adding-non-spatial-attributes-using-geoserver?rq=1)
- [How to insert non-spatial data through WFS-T insert?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31915/how-to-insert-non-spatial-data-through-wfs-t-insert?rq=1)

And from openlayers-dev: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-dev/2007-April/000520.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the attribute to the feature before the wfs-commit:

```
// feat is the feature with the area the user drawn
feat.attributes.INVADED_BY_ARMY_ID = 42;
```

Of course, you should save somewhere the army id...

Comment: Yes that's correct - all attributes of feature are saved to according database fields. There's one more thing to remember - if you want to update attributes of existing feature, you have to set feature's state to OpenLayers.State.UPDATE


`feat.attributes.INVADED_BY_ARMY_ID = 42;

/* Update state, if it is not set allready. Otherwise you may overwrite INSERT state */
if (!feature.state)
    feature.state = OpenLayers.State.UPDATE;
saveStrategy.save();`

Comment: Nice answer. I will mark it once I have tried it in practise, it may take a week unfortunately.

Comment: Tested and it works. Perfect.